# Given integers $a, b, c, d$ satisfy: $|a-b|+|b-c|+|c-d|+|d-a|=a^{2022}+2023.$ Find the smallest natural $x$ value if $a^{12} \equiv x \pmod {16}.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given integers $a, b, c, d$ satisfy:
$$|a-b|+|b-c|+|c-d|+|d-a|=a^{2022}+2023.$$
Find the smallest natural $x$ value if $a^{12} \equiv x \pmod {16}.$

**ORIGINAL:** I still have no ideas for solving it. I'd love to hear some hints of this problem.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT:** Shoutout to Robert Murraygramlich for the hint, much obliged.

So far, we can easily prove that $|a-b|+|b-c|+|c-d|+|d-a|$ is even, through many ways.

The hard way is to evaluate each case of the following: all are even, 1 number is odd, 2 numbers are odd, 3 numbers are odd, and all odd.

The easy way is that the left hand side of the equation has the same parity as the expression:

$$|a-b+b-c+c-d+d-a|,$$

which is just 0, an even number, thus the left hand side is even.

Therefore, the right hand side is also even, so $a^{2022}$ must be odd, yielding:
$$a^{2022} \equiv 1; 3; 5; 7; 9; 11; 13; 15 \pmod {16}$$
$$\implies (a^{2022})^2 = a^{4044}=(a^{12})^{337} \equiv 1; 9 \pmod {16}$$

From this point, I may become the stupidest person in this forum only because of this following statement: since $gcd(337, 16)=1$, we finally have:

$$a^{12} \equiv 1; 9 \pmod{16}.$$

I say that because I am just a number theory newbie and I cannot find any theorems on the Internet nor in my number theory homework notebook.

Talking about my homework notebook though, this problem (I would say) is the fifth hardest problem remaining (although I was a fool for not noticing the fact that the 4 integers are just a trap).

Comment: Welcome to MSE! We are NOT your friendly neighborhood Homework Answering Service. And this question--no effort no context shown on your part, makes many of us salty. It also goes against the MSE Guidelines as well too. So edit telling us where this came from and your efforts thus far. Pls & Thx

Comment: You can quite easily also confirm this manually, but note that all perfect squares of odd integers are congruent to $1$ modulo $8$, i.e., $a^2\equiv 1\pmod{8}\;\to\;a^2=8k+1$ for some integer $k$. Thus, $a^4=(8k+1)^2=64k^2+16k+1\equiv 1\pmod{16}$. Since $12=3(4)$, what does that mean about the possible values of $a^{12}$ modulo $16$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a hint on *one* method to solve: we ask can $x=0$ as $0$ is the smallest value mod $16$.$$a^{12}\equiv a^{12\ \mathrm{mod}\ \phi(16)} \equiv a^{4} \equiv \begin{cases}0&n\ \mathrm{even}\\1&n\ \mathrm{odd}\end{cases} \mod{16}$$ It is also good to note, that if $a^{12}\equiv 0 \mod 16$, then $a^{2022} \equiv 0 \mod 16$. From here, we can simplify the equation to find:
$$b + |b-c| + |c-d| + d \equiv 7 \mod 16$$ Which is impossible, as this will equate to an even number on the left and an odd on the right. Next, we would look at $x=1$, to see whether there exist any values for $x$.

This method of solving math (I assume this is competition) problems is called the extremal principle, and is useful to know. I like Problem-solving strategies by Arthur Engel. This is also not necessarily the best solution method for this problem, but it will work with enough time.